# Toggling a persistent tooltip

Tags: autohotkey

I want to create a few tooltips that dump info about a window based on `MouseGetPos`:

1. `^Space` = The tooltip is toggled on and off and follows the mouse
2. `^+Space` = The tooltip appears temporarily, then disappears
3. `^!+Space` = The tooltip is toggled and appears in the lower-left corner of the screen

However, the tooltip does not disappear for 1 & 2. 3 Gives an error 'action not defined'.

Here's my current code:

```wiki
#CommentFlag //
Toggle := False

^Space:: // Toggle the tooltip and follow the mouse

    If (Toggle = False) {

        Toggle := True
        #Persistent
        SetTimer, WatchCursor // If I have just 'WatchCursor', without '#Persistent' and 'SetTimer', I get an "Action not defined" error

    } Else If (Toggle = True) {

        Toggle := False
        ToolTip

    } 
Return

^+Space:: // Tooltip follows mouse, but disappears after 1 second

    #Persistent
    SetTimer, WatchCursor, 1000

Return

^!+Space:: // Tooltip appears at 1511, 3010

    #Persistent
    WatchCursor2 // Error: This line does not contain a recognized action

Return

WatchCursor:
MouseGetPos, x, y, id, control
WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %id%
WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %id%
ToolTip, -- Window Info --`n`tahk_id:`t%id%`n`tahk_class:`t%class%`n`tTitle:`t%title%`n`tControl:`t%control%`n`n-- Mouse Pos --`n`tX:`t%x%`n`tY:`t%y%

WatchCursor2:
MouseGetPos, x, y, id, control
WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %id%
WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %id%
ToolTip, -- Window Info --`n`tahk_id:`t%id%`n`tahk_class:`t%class%`n`tTitle:`t%title%`n`tControl:`t%control%`n`n-- Mouse Pos --`n`tX:`t%x%`n`tY:`t%y%,1511,3010
```

Comment: To jump to a label you need `goto`.

Comment: I now realize I can get most of this information with Window Spy in the [SciTE4AutoHotKey](http://fincs.ahk4.net/scite4ahk/) Script Editor. However, I would still like to understand how to toggle a persistent tooltip.

Comment: I think @wOxxOm meant [GoSub](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gosub.htm) to call a label/subroutine once. That will solve the undefined action problem. Also, every subroutine should be concluded with a `return`. In your code, each call of `WatchCursor` will subsequently call `WatchCursor2` due to a missing return. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: @MCL So you're saying I need a Return at the end of each WatchCursor? Like `Tooltip, display some stuff Return`? That makes sense, I couldn't figure out why everything was calling WatchCursor2.

Comment: Yes. Subsequent subroutines (also hotkey routines) will jump over to the next routine until a `Return` or `Exit` is encountered.

Answer (score 2):

The AutoHotkey script below, should give you the exact functionality
you require. I have made some amendments and comments,
that should explain the problems you experienced.

```
#CommentFlag //
// #Persistent is not necessary for this script,
// the presence of at least one hotkey,
// is one way to make a script persistent

Toggle := False

// #p::Pause

^Space:: // Toggle the tooltip and follow the mouse

    If (Toggle = False) {

        Toggle := True
        vTickCount1 := A_TickCount
        SetTimer, WatchCursor

    } Else If (Toggle = True) {

        Toggle := False
        SetTimer, WatchCursor, Off
        // ToolTip

    }

Return

^+Space:: // Tooltip follows mouse, but disappears after 1 second

    SetTimer, WatchCursor1, -1000 // negative to run once and then stop
    MouseGetPos, x, y, id, control
    WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %id%
    WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %id%
    ToolTip, -- Window Info --`n`tahk_id:`t%id%`n`tahk_class:`t%class%`n`tTitle:`t%title%`n`tControl:`t%control%`n`n-- Mouse Pos --`n`tX:`t%x%`n`tY:`t%y%

Return

^!+Space:: // Tooltip appears at 1511, 3010

Gosub WatchCursor2

Return

WatchCursor1:
ToolTip
Return

WatchCursor:
MouseGetPos, x, y, id, control
WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %id%
WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %id%
ToolTip, -- Window Info --`n`tahk_id:`t%id%`n`tahk_class:`t%class%`n`tTitle:`t%title%`n`tControl:`t%control%`n`n-- Mouse Pos --`n`tX:`t%x%`n`tY:`t%y%

// if (A_TickCount - vTickCount1 > 5000)
// {
// SetTimer, WatchCursor, Off
// ToolTip
// }
Return // without this line the lines below in WatchCursor2 will also be triggered

WatchCursor2:
MouseGetPos, x, y, id, control
WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %id%
WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %id%
ToolTip, -- Window Info --`n`tahk_id:`t%id%`n`tahk_class:`t%class%`n`tTitle:`t%title%`n`tControl:`t%control%`n`n-- Mouse Pos --`n`tX:`t%x%`n`tY:`t%y%,1511,3010
Return
```

Note: This was quite a nice script and enjoyable to work with.
Note: AutoHotkey's AccViewer is a very useful script for retrieving information about windows and controls, iWB2 Learner is also useful for retrieving information about web elements in Internet Explorer.

Comment: I appreciate your response. Your code solves a lot of issues I was facing, and for that I am grateful. However, it doesn't address my main question *Is it possible to toggle a persistent tooltip?* Instead it replaces persistency with a timer: `if (A_TickCount - vTickCount1 > 5000) SetTimer, WatchCursor, Off` This does not allow <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to truly toggle.

Comment: OK, I think I've fixed that for you now, in my second answer I've just added. Thanks for the response.

Comment: You don't need to post a second answer, just edit your first one.

Comment: Well, I was in two minds, 1.5 votes beats 0.5 votes, I've removed the second answer, and edited the first one.

Comment: Very cool. That script works. However, my original question was not addressed. If it's not possible to toggle a persistent entity, that's fine, just address it in your answer, then I can give you credit.

Comment: I found [this in the FAQ's](https://autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#repeat); It says I can create a `#p` command to "`Pause`" a script. Not sure if it will work for persisting though. Do you have any experience with that?

Comment: Hmm, I believe the issue you have now is that when you press Ctrl+Space to turn the ToolTip off,
you want it to pause rather than disappear.
I've amended the script to do this.
-- I see Pause as an emergency break, to stop
current activity by the script. But then like many things in programming,
it's hard to say anything without caveats. I've added Pause in, if you uncomment it,
and toggle it, it can effectively pause/unpause the ToolTip, so it could potentially
add functionality. Link: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Pause.htm

Comment: No, I just want to know if it's possible to toggle something that is persistent. Look at my original example: It has a tooltip that is persistent. You have successfully demonstrated that persistent is not needed, but what if it was persistent? How do I "turn off" the tooltip if it is persistent? Is it even possible to "turn off"? I guess it can be "paused" but pausing the script seems like it will make the other hotkeys in the script not work.

Comment: OK, well if you uncomment the current line 17, '// ToolTip', the script will be as it was before.